# Create a dropdown list with project features

Tags: tfs, customization, dropdown

I create a couple Features to my TFS Project and I need to insert a dropdown list into Requeriment work item. 
How can I list my features into a dropdown list?

[See my feature list and tab with custom field - features list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoV6d.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in TFS.

Instead TFS/VSTS uses links to create traceability between work items. You can read more on: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293534.aspx

You can set a single feature as a Parent of a Requirement, and then add additional related items.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TFS 2015 or later, you can custom work item control and retrieve corresponding work items through [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/overview) and append to dropdown control.

You can refer to this article ([Multi Value Control source code](https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WitCustomControls/VS2015.2/WitCustomControls.WebAccess/MultiValueControl/CodePlex.WitCustomControls.MultiValueControl.js)) to build your custom work item control. (Call REST API in _render function to retrieve work items)